Error occurred in handler for 'GUEST_VIEW_MANAGER_CALL': Error: ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'http://10.4.174.203:3001/#/home?channel=xybank&entrance=cpjl'
I am using electron webview tag to load the page url, click the button to change the url, only the url parameters are different, but the error is reported
enter image description hereenter image description here
Hope to get your help and answers
